# ModelCache.safeGet(androidProjectResult.androidProject::getNdkVersion, "") must not be null

Tags: android-studio, gradle

When I Updated the Android Studio to the Bumblebee 2021.1.1 I got this error:

```
ModelCache.safeGet(androidProjectResult.androidProject::getNdkVersion, "") must not be null
```

I have already added ndk.dir to local.properties but I still have the error.

```
sdk.dir=/path/to/sdk
ndk.dir=/path/to/ndk
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem?

Comment: @rozina No I reverted to the previous version (Arctic Fox)

Comment: you can also get rid of this problem if you change gradle version to latest and also change gradle.properties to latest version. If you create new project with c++ project form template you can't see any ndk path or ndk version

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Add ndk path in `android.ndkPath`

**Or**

Add `ndkVersion '23.0.7599858'` (If you use this approach then in some case you have to add version in other library module if they use ndk)

[image]

---

> You can also add this using **File-> Project Structure**

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 2):

The value for ndk.dir should no longer be set in your app's local.properties file, and support for this ndk.dir setting will be removed in a future version. The Android Gradle Plugin sets the NDK version by default, but if you need a specific version of the NDK, you can set android.ndkVersion in build.gradle.

1. Remove `ndk.dir=/path/to/ndk` from the local.properties.
2. go to `build.gradle` under android section add `ndkVersion='required ndk version'`

ex:

android {

```
ndkVersion '23.1.7779620'
```

}

Reference : [Android office doc's](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?utm_source=android-studio#4-0-0-ndk-dir)

Comment: I have already added "ndkVersion" to build.gradle file but still have the problem.

Comment: I don't have ndk.dir in local.properties but still get the error

Answer (score 1):

Google has provide this fix in **Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2** ([Issue link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/216261600))

So, updating my Android Studio to Bumblebee patch-2 solved this error.
Now I need not to add the ndk paths as suggested in other answers.

[Google Android Studio changelog](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2022/02/android-studio-bumblebee-202111-patch-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

**ndk.dir=/path/Android/Sdk/ndk 

sdk.dir=/path/Android/Sdk**

Try to define like this

Comment: I tried this but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Follow these two steps to solve the issue

1. Go to SDK Manager>SDK Tools> NDK > Uninstall all
2. Go to the ndk directory and see if it's empty, If it is not, delete the files
3. Install a new copy of ndk from SDK manager
4. in your local.properties gives your path as

```
sdk.dir=D\:\\AndroidFiles
ndk.dir=D\:\\AndroidFiles\\ndk\\23.0.7599858
```